# Boost::Spirit Expression Parser

Tags: c++, boost-spirit, boost-phoenix

I have another problem with my boost::spirit parser.

```
template<typename Iterator>
struct expression: qi::grammar<Iterator, ast::expression(), ascii::space_type> {
    expression() :
        expression::base_type(expr) {
        number %= lexeme[double_];
        varname %= lexeme[alpha >> *(alnum | '_')];

        binop = (expr >> '+' >> expr)[_val = construct<ast::binary_op<ast::add>>(_1,_2)]
              | (expr >> '-' >> expr)[_val = construct<ast::binary_op<ast::sub>>(_1,_2)]
              | (expr >> '*' >> expr)[_val = construct<ast::binary_op<ast::mul>>(_1,_2)]
              | (expr >> '/' >> expr)[_val = construct<ast::binary_op<ast::div>>(_1,_2)] ;

        expr %= number | varname | binop;
    }

    qi::rule<Iterator, ast::expression(), ascii::space_type> expr;
    qi::rule<Iterator, ast::expression(), ascii::space_type> binop;
    qi::rule<Iterator, std::string(), ascii::space_type> varname;
    qi::rule<Iterator, double(), ascii::space_type> number;
};
```

This was my parser. It parsed `"3.1415"` and `"var"` just fine, but when I tried to parse `"1+2"` it tells me `parse failed`. I've then tried to change the `binop` rule to

```
    binop = expr >>
           (('+' >> expr)[_val = construct<ast::binary_op<ast::add>>(_1, _2)]
          | ('-' >> expr)[_val = construct<ast::binary_op<ast::sub>>(_1, _2)]
          | ('*' >> expr)[_val = construct<ast::binary_op<ast::mul>>(_1, _2)]
          | ('/' >> expr)[_val = construct<ast::binary_op<ast::div>>(_1, _2)]);
```

But now it's of course not able to build the AST, because `_1` and `_2` are set differently. I have only seen something like `_r1` mentioned, but as a boost-Newbie I am not quite able to understand how `boost::phoenix` and `boost::spirit` interact.

How to solve this?

Comment: also interesting: http://www.gamedev.net/topic/416784-recursive-descent-parsing-handling-left-associativity/

Answer (score 22, accepted):

It isn't entirely clear to me what you are trying to achieve. Most importantly, are you not worried about operator associativity? I'll just show simple answers based on using right-recursion - this leads to *left-associative operators* being parsed.

The straight answer to your *visible* question would be to juggle a `fusion::vector2<char, ast::expression>` - which isn't really any fun, especially in *Phoenix lambda* semantic actions. (I'll show below, what that looks like).

Meanwhile I think you should read up on the Spirit docs

- [here](http://boost-spirit.com/old_docs/v1_6/doc/faq.html#left_recursion) in the *old* Spirit docs (eliminating left recursion); Though the syntax no longer applies, Spirit still generates LL recursive descent parsers, so the concept behind left-recursion still applies. The code below shows this applied to Spirit Qi
- [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/libs/spirit/example/qi/calc_utree_naive.cpp): the Qi examples contain three `calculator` samples, which should give you a hint on why operator associativity matters, and how you would express a grammar that captures the associativity of binary operators. Obviously, it also shows how to support *parenthesized expressions* to override the default evaluation order.

### Code:

I have three version of code that works, parsing input like:

```
std::string input("1/2+3-4*5");
```

into an `ast::expression` grouped like (using BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG):

```xml
<expr>
  ....
  <success></success>
  <attributes>[[1, [2, [3, [4, 5]]]]]</attributes>
</expr>
```

> The links to the code are here:
>
> - [step_#1_reduce_semantic_actions.cpp](https://gist.github.com/267acc43ac7ee276e889#file_step_1_reduce_semantic_actions.cpp)
> - [step_#2_drop_rule.cpp](https://gist.github.com/267acc43ac7ee276e889#file_step_2_drop_rule.cpp)
> - [step_#0_vector2.cpp](https://gist.github.com/267acc43ac7ee276e889#file_step_0_vector2.cpp)

#### Step 1: [Reduce semantic actions](https://gist.github.com/267acc43ac7ee276e889#file_step_1_reduce_semantic_actions.cpp)

First thing, I'd get rid of the alternative parse expressions per operator; this leads to excessive backtracking<sup>1</sup>. Also, as you've found out, it makes the grammar hard to maintain. So, here is a simpler variation that uses a function for the semantic action:

<sub><sup>1</sup>check that using BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG!</sub>

```c
static ast::expression make_binop(char discriminant, 
     const ast::expression& left, const ast::expression& right)
{
    switch(discriminant)
    {
        case '+': return ast::binary_op<ast::add>(left, right);
        case '-': return ast::binary_op<ast::sub>(left, right);
        case '/': return ast::binary_op<ast::div>(left, right);
        case '*': return ast::binary_op<ast::mul>(left, right);
    }
    throw std::runtime_error("unreachable in make_binop");
}

// rules:
number %= lexeme[double_];
varname %= lexeme[alpha >> *(alnum | '_')];

simple = varname | number;
binop = (simple >> char_("-+*/") >> expr) 
    [ _val = phx::bind(make_binop, qi::_2, qi::_1, qi::_3) ]; 

expr = binop | simple;
```

#### Step 2: [Remove redundant rules, use *`_val`*](https://gist.github.com/267acc43ac7ee276e889#file_step_2_drop_rule.cpp)

As you can see, this has the potential to reduce complexity. It is only a small step now, to remove the binop intermediate (which has become quite redundant):

```
number %= lexeme[double_];
varname %= lexeme[alpha >> *(alnum | '_')];

simple = varname | number;
expr = simple [ _val = _1 ] 
    > *(char_("-+*/") > expr) 
            [ _val = phx::bind(make_binop, qi::_1, _val, qi::_2) ]
    > eoi;
```

As you can see,

- within the `expr` rule, the `_val` lazy placeholder is used as a pseudo-local variable that accumulates the binops. Across rules, you'd have to use `qi::locals<ast::expression>` for such an approach. (This was your question regarding `_r1`).
- there are now explicit expectation points, making the grammar more robust
- the `expr` rule no longer needs to be an auto-rule (`expr =` instead of `expr %=`)

#### Step 0: [Wrestle fusion types directly](https://gist.github.com/267acc43ac7ee276e889#file_step_0_vector2.cpp)

Finally, for fun and gory, let me show how you could have handled your suggested code, along with the shifting bindings of _1, _2 etc.:

```
static ast::expression make_binop(
        const ast::expression& left, 
        const boost::fusion::vector2<char, ast::expression>& op_right)
{
    switch(boost::fusion::get<0>(op_right))
    {
        case '+': return ast::binary_op<ast::add>(left, boost::fusion::get<1>(op_right));
        case '-': return ast::binary_op<ast::sub>(left, boost::fusion::get<1>(op_right));
        case '/': return ast::binary_op<ast::div>(left, boost::fusion::get<1>(op_right));
        case '*': return ast::binary_op<ast::mul>(left, boost::fusion::get<1>(op_right));
    }
    throw std::runtime_error("unreachable in make_op");
}

// rules:
expression::base_type(expr) {
number %= lexeme[double_];
varname %= lexeme[alpha >> *(alnum | '_')];

simple = varname | number;
binop %= (simple >> (char_("-+*/") > expr)) 
    [ _val = phx::bind(make_binop, qi::_1, qi::_2) ]; // note _2!!!

expr %= binop | simple;
```

As you can see, not nearly as much fun writing the `make_binop` function that way!