# Boost::Spirit result of phrase_parse

Tags: c++, parsing, boost-spirit

Hello everybody I am new to boost and boost::spirit, so I am sorry for noob question.

When I use `qi::phrase_parse`function, the function returns only bool variable which indicates whether parsing has been successful or not, but I don't know where I can find the result of parsing ...some sort of syntax tree etc.

If I use macro `#define BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG` XML representation of tree is printed on standard output, but these nodes has to be stored somewhere. Can you help me please?

Comment: Without a code sample it is rather hard to answer your question

Comment: I don't think any spirit question is a noob question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can 'bind' attribute references. `qi::parse`, `qi::phrase_parse` (and related) accept variadic arguments that will be used to receive the exposed attributes.

A simplistic example is: (**EDIT** included a `utree` example too)

```
#include <boost/fusion/adapted.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/support_utree.hpp>

namespace qi = boost::spirit::qi;

int main()
{
    using namespace qi;

    std::string input("1 2 3 4 5");
    std::string::const_iterator F(input.begin()), f(F), l(input.end());

    std::vector<int> ints;
    if (qi::phrase_parse(f = F, l, *qi::int_, qi::space, ints))
        std::cout << ints.size() << " ints parsed\n";

    int i;
    std::string s;
    // it is variadic:
    if (qi::parse(f = F, l, "1 2 " >> qi::int_ >> +qi::char_, i, s))
        std::cout << "i: " << i << ", s: " << s << '\n';

    std::pair<int, std::string> data;
    // any compatible sequence can be used:
    if (qi::parse(f = F, l, "1 2 " >> qi::int_ >> +qi::char_, data))
        std::cout << "first: " << data.first << ", second: " << data.second << '\n';

    // using utree:
    boost::spirit::utree tree;
    if (qi::parse(f = F, l, "1 2 " >> qi::int_ >> qi::as_string [ +qi::char_ ], tree))
        std::cout << "tree: " << tree << '\n';

}
```

Outputs:

```
5 ints parsed
i: 3, s:  4 5
first: 3, second:  4 5
tree: ( 3 " 4 5" )
```

A few samples of parsers with 'AST' like data structures:

- [Boolean expression (grammar) parser in c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8706356/boolean-expression-grammar-parser-in-c/8707598#8707598)
- [Boost::Spirit Expression Parser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8464969/boostspirit-expression-parser/8468822#8468822)

If you want to have a very generic AST structure, look at `utree`: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_50_0/libs/spirit/doc/html/spirit/support/utree.html